# How to (properly) analyze the sex ratio

Tags: chi-squared-test, ratio

Few weeks ago, I was listening to a "HowToDoScience" lecture.
In the section which focused on appropriate statistics in articles the lecturer said:

> **Person who will analyse the sex ratio by the chi-square will be fired!!!**

I was totally amazed. I thought that chi-square is commonly used in such situation.

For example if I have data like this:

```
# number of born...
boys   <- 160
# ...and number of born
girls <- 180

# And our null hypothesis is:
# The chances to give birth to a boy or girl are equal.
# ...so our given probabilities are 1/2 and 1/2
```

*My solution will be:*

```
chisq.test(c(160, 180), p = c(1/2, 1/2))

#   Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#  
#  data:  c(160, 180)
#  X-squared = 1.1765, df = 1, p-value = 0.2781
```

**Is there some better solution how to analyze sex ratio?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use binomial test, since it does not depend on an approximation to a continuous distribution like the chi-squared test:

```
binom.test(c(160, 180), p=0.5)

#   Exact binomial test
#  
#  data:  c(160, 180)
#  number of successes = 160, number of trials = 340, p-value = 0.3028
#  alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
#  95 percent confidence interval:
#   0.4165216 0.5251716
#  sample estimates:
#  probability of success 
#               0.4705882
```